# Can we remove `fer` tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fer

Just 1 recent, -3 votes, closed, question.  Fer has no explanation on its use.  Doesn't seem an obvious acronym.

What's best way to flag an unnecessary tag for removal?

(p.s. I removed it from the question after JJJ's answer.  Also limits the temptation to add another downvote to that question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to do anything about it.

Tags only exist in the context of questions. So one way to get rid of the tag would be to remove it from all questions.

In this case though, that doesn't seem necessary. Only one question has the [fer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fer) tag, and that question is currently closed with a -3 score. As such, the question will either have to be improved or [it will be cleaned up by the community user](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

If and when that happens, the tag will be removed too. It may take a day for some automatic process to remove it from the tag list, according to [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279921).

Comment: ok, txs.  I wasn't aware of tags disappearing when not attached to questions.  Which makes sense and solves the "problem".

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica yea, the tag list contains a lot of tags which don't seem to have any questions. Those are actually synonyms of other tags. So if you click on any of those then they should point to the main tag. For example, [u.s.] links to [united-states].

Comment: Yeah, but `fer` will not be cluttering up that list if not attached to a question, right?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica no, it will be removed when there are no more non-deleted questions with that tag. See also the link I just added. :)